# Can't listen backspace events in Ionic/Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic/Cordova app and I'm having some issues when dealing with number input for Samsung devices, they simply [don't show decimal separator when the input type is number](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=258224). If it were a native app, I could use numberDecimal type, however, I couldn't find a similar input type in HTML. To solve this problem, I've decided create a simple Angularjs's directive, so a mask could put the decimal separator automatically:

```
angular.module('number.mask', [])
.directive('numberMask', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            element.on('focus',function(){
                this.value = this.value;
            });

            element.on('keyup',function(event){
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(ctrl.$viewValue)) {
                    return ctrl.$viewValue;
                }
                var newValue=ctrl.$viewValue;
                if(event.keyCode=== 8)
                    newValue/=10;
                else if(newValue.toString().indexOf('.')===-1 && newValue.toString().indexOf(',')===-1)
                    newValue/=100;
                else
                    newValue*=10;
                newValue=parseFloat(Math.round(newValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                ctrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I'm almost there, but, when I touch in backspace button, nothing is fired. All the other buttons, including paste button, fires at least keydown and keyup, but the backspace don't fire none of these and neither keypress. So the question is, how can I listen for events when backspace button is tapped in Android virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe using a hammer to kill a fly but one approach is to use a touch library, for example [this library](https://github.com/rasismeiro/touch) catches all events and fires a simple touch event. It is also useful for dealing with some devices which fire touch events differently. In my case I had to use it because Android 4.4.x devices were firing touch events strangely.